# Update SRC of Image-Tag in HTML after PHP Image Upload

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

So I've managed to create `XMLHttpRequest` image upload. After the upload is finished I would like to update my `<image src="">` in the `html` to reflect the changes.

I do this in `html`:

```
<img id="profileImg" <?php echo 'src="'.$profileURL.'"'; ?> >
```

..when a new picture gets uploaded I send a `XMLHttpRequest` to update the database and the filesystem respectively; the `php` used looks like this:

```
<?php

// getting stuff from XMLHttpRequest

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

    // saving new file url ($target_file) into db        
    // on page refesh $profileURL would be equal to $target_file

    ?>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById("profileImg").src = "<?php echo $target_file ?>";
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

I thought nesting the javascript inside my php file would make it update the `src` for the `imgae`-tag aswell.. However it doesn't work.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you post all of your code? This excerpt even with comments is not a whole story. ... Still post all of your code pls, but your AJAX function should be coded in such a way that *it* returns the new image filename, if that is how you want that to work.

Comment: i suspect `$target_file` is not publicly accessible. at least try to check the output of the `src`.

Comment: use the ajax callback function to update the DOM with the img src

Comment: `window.onload` ... the page has already been loaded then, this might never trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic full example of how one might use an `XMLHttpRequest` to upload an image and then use the ajax callback function to manipulate the DOM - in this instance to set the image source attribute and thus display the image.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        if( !empty( $_FILES['fileToUpload'] ) ){

            $obj=(object)$_FILES['fileToUpload'];
            $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
            $name=$obj->name;

            $filename = sprintf('upload__%s', $name );

            file_put_contents( sprintf( '%s/%s', __DIR__, $filename ), file_get_contents( $tmp ) );

            header('Content-Type: text/plain');
            http_response_code(200);

            exit( $filename );
        }


        http_response_code(404);
        exit(false);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',e=>{
                const ajax=function(url,params,callback){
                    let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onload=function(){
                        if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )callback.call( this, this.response )
                    };
                    xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');
                    xhr.send( params );
                };

                const ajaxcallback=function(r){
                    document.querySelector('form img').src=r
                }

                const filehandler=function(e){
                    ajax( location.href, new FormData( e.target.parentNode ), ajaxcallback  )
                };

                document.querySelector('[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', filehandler );
            });
        </script>
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type='file' name='fileToUpload' />
            <img src='' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll look into it as soon as possible..